# NSMutableDictionary entry corrupted after departing from the method where entry was added

Tags: macos, nsmutabledictionary, corruption

I use setObject:forKey: to add an object of type Rresource to a NSMutableDictionary named: resourceLib.

Then I immediately look at what's actually in the dictionary and it's OK.

When I try to look at it again in another object's method, the proper key is present but a reference to a string property "url" cases a list of error messages including:

2016-09-28 11:32:42.636 testa[760:16697] -[__NSCFString url]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x600000456350

Rresource object is defined as:

```
@interface Rresource : NSObject
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSString* url;
@property (nonatomic,strong)NSMutableArray* resourceNotesArray;
@property(nonatomic,strong)NSString* name;
@property(nonatomic,strong)NSString* resourceUniqueID;
@property(nonatomic)BOOL isResourceDirty;
```

This method in a ViewController adds the Rresource to the NSMutableDictionary

```
-(void)saveResource
{
Rresource* resource = self.currentResource;
Rresource* temp;
if (resource)
{
    if ( resource.isResourceDirty)
    {
        [self.model.resourceLib setObject:resource forKey:resource.resourceUniqueID];
        temp = [self.model.resourceLib objectForKey:resource.resourceUniqueID];
    }
}
```

}

Resource and temp contain identical info showing the info was added correctly.

In model's method the following causes the error message described above.

```
for (Rresource* resource in self.resourceLib)
{
    NSString* string = resource.url;
}
```

where model contains:

```
@property(nonatomic,strong)NSMutableDictionary* resourceLib;
```

and :

```
@implementation Model


- (instancetype)init
{
self = [super init];
if (self)
{
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSLibraryDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    self.path = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingString:@"/Application Support/E2"];
    BOOL exists = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:self.path withIntermediateDirectories:NO attributes:nil error:nil];
    if (!exists)
    {
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:self.path withIntermediateDirectories:NO attributes:nil error:nil];
    }
    self.resourceLibPath = [NSString pathWithComponents:@[self.path,@"resources"]];
    self.resourceLib = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
    self.noteLibPath = [NSString pathWithComponents:@[self.path, @"notes"]];
    self.noteLib = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
}
return self;
```

I have found this question difficult to ask clearly even after spending several hours formulating it.  I apologize.

I've tried pretty much everything for about a week.  I'm stumped.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this entry on Enumeration](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Collections/Articles/Enumerators.html), when you iterate over a dictionary using the fast enumeration syntax, you're iterating over its keys. In the above code sample you're assuming the enumeration happens over its values. What you're effectively doing is casting an `NSString` object as an `Rresource`, and sending it a selector only an actual `Rresource` object can respond to.

This should fix the loop:

```
for (NSString* key in self.resourceLib)
{
    NSString* string = [self.resourceLib objectForKey:key].url;
}
```